# Use awk for values stored in a variable?

Tags: awk, grep

I want to do an if statement that compares the values of a command that reads header information of two image files. First I pass output of the command to the variables

```
~$ hd1=$(<command> <file1> | grep dim3)
~$ hd2=$(<command> <file2> | grep dim3)
~$ if [ $hd1 = $hd2 ];
    ~$ then
       etc
```

The output of my command has alot of fields

```
~$ <command> <file>
~$ sizeof_hdr     348
   data_type      INT16
   dim0           3
   dim1           256
   dim2           256
   dim3           70
   dim4           1
   dim5           1
   dim6           1
   dim7           1
   vox_units      mm
   time_units     s
   datatype       4
   nbyper         2
   bitpix         16
   pixdim0        0.000000
   pixdim1        0.828125
   pixdim2        0.828125
   pixdim3        2.199998
   pixdim4        4.177372
   pixdim5        0.000000
   pixdim6        0.000000
   pixdim7        0.000000
   vox_offset     352
   file_type      NIFTI-1+
```

So I use grep to get the one that I care about here. The problem is the output of my command includes a "dim3" field and a "pixdim3" field, and using `grep` prints both, like this:

```
~$ dim3 70 pixdim3 2.19
```

I really just need compare the second column for both files. I tried using `awk`, but it wouldn't work because they are variables and not files. Is there anyway to print just the second column, or better yet only grep the dim3 field?

Comment: Please add an example of the output of `<command> file`.

Comment: Have you considered using `grep -w` (or suitable word boundary anchors) to limit the match to only the whole word `dim3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `grep` by

```
... | awk '$1 == "dim3" { print $2;}'
```

this will filter out result on first field being `pim3`, and will only print second field.